# Replacement of array elements with strings in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace the elements of an array (which contains numbers) with strings.For example I want "1" to be replaced with "a", I want "2" to be replaced with "b", and I want "3" to be replaced with "c". I did the following and didn't work for me. Can anyone suggest a way to resolve the issue?

```
test = np.where(test==1, "a", test)
test = np.where(test==2, "b", test)
test = np.where(test==3, "c", test)
```

Comment: Do note that `numpy.ndarrays` cannot contain mixed types, unless you plan to store plain `object`s (defeating most of the reasons to use `numpy`) or numbers as strings.

Comment: What error(s) did you get.  We don't like to see "didn't work' without explanation.  Check the `test` array `dtype` at each step.

Answer (score 1):

your looking for `np.select`
it works by giving `np.select` a list of conditions, and a list of choices, and if the condition is true, it will replace that value with the same index from the choice list, if not, then it will use the default value, the 3rd positional argument in `np.select`

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,3,2,5]) 
condlist = [test==1 ,test==2, test==3]
choicelist = ['a', 'b', 'c']

test = np.select(condlist, choicelist, test)
test
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(['a', 'b', 'c', '4', '5', '6', '7', 'a', 'c', 'b', '5'],
  dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, after the first modification, *dtype* of the array will be changed from `int` or `float` to `<U11`, so, `test==2` and `test==3`for the next lines must be written as strings. If:

```
test = np.array([[1, 5, 6], [1, 3, 2]])
# dtype --> int32
```

So, after the first line:

```
test = np.where(test==1, "a", test)
# dtype --> <U11
```

So, `2` and `3` must be written as string:

```
test = np.where(test=='2', "b", test)
test = np.where(test=='3', "c", test)
```

It is the cause of the error. [`np.select` is another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73506852/13394817).